# Create rails scaffolding from mysql workbench's EER diagram

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql-workbench, scaffolding, erd

Is there a way to use an EER diagram one did on mysql workbench to generate rails scaffolding?

I have an EER diagram with a lot of tables and relationships and column types and restrictions (Not null, auto incremental, etc) and I'm wondering whether I can save myself some time and avoid creating the scaffolding on rails by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the plugin forums post, which contains a number of links to Rails solutions. I don't know if they are still active, but at least there is a starting point: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,208229,208229#msg-208229.